# Java - Convert hex to decimal - make a string = the correct number

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

**ERROR WAS DUE TO A MISTAKE WHICH WAS OVERLOOKED**

I recently created a Java program that converts an rgb value to hexadecimal.  Now I am trying to make a program that will do the opposite.  I already figured out the algorithm I am going to use, I just need to convert the characters `A - F` to the values `10 - 15`.  Seems simple right?  This is where I hit my problem.

Here is the code I have so far.  A string is fed into `nums()` which then checks it against the array `abc`.  Once a match is found it takes takes the string `a` and converts it to an integer, then takes `i` and will add 10 in order to get the right number.

```
class TextToNum {
  String[] abc = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
  public int nums(String a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
      if (a == abc[i]) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(a.trim());
        a = i + 10;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
gbConv.java:52: incompatible types
found   : int
required: java.lang.String
                a = Integer.parseInt(a.trim());
                                    ^
rgbConv.java:53: incompatible types
found   : int
required: java.lang.String
                a = i + 10;
                      ^
rgbConv.java:56: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
        return a;
               ^
```

It is obvious that something is wrong with the `Integer.parseInt()` but I am not sure how to fix it.  I have been looking on the web and I can't find anything.  Any suggestions / tutorials would be a great help.

Comment: Pass radix or add 0x before letter on parsing.

Comment: Why don't you just use int a = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16) ?

Comment: The errors are telling you exactly what the problem is. You are trying to use `a` as both a `String` and an `int` in this code. Also, *never* use `==` to compare `String`s. That doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I realized that after I posted the question.  I went back to delete it but there was already an answer so I couldn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To convert a hex string to an int, you could simply use [`Integer.parseInt(str, 16)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 9):

Why dont you try which is already available.

```
  Color.decode("hex string");
```

Comment: Why down vote? Please explain.

Comment: I dunno, this is much better than parseInt and bunch of bitwise operations. +1

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(String str)` works only if `str` contains integer. Like if you have string as `str="12345"` `Integer.parseInt(str)` results `12345` as integer.

But in your case mentioned you are passing either one of `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"`.

Comment: `-1` you mentioned a good tip but didn't solve the problem anymore, I believe this must be a comment to Smit's answer but not an answer